# Can't find where the socket configuration is in XAMPP for Windows

Tags: php, xampp, lampp

I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1 in a PHP project.

I've installed XAMPP 1.7 in Windows 7 64 bits with the installer we can find in xampp.org.
I've changed the port of apache from 80 and 443 to 81 and 442 since I'm using IIS as well.
I didn't installed anything as a service, I'm using the Control Panel to start/stop mysql, apache, etc.

My problem is that my unit test  are failing, and the context is that I'm developing the project with two guys who are working on Macs.

They have a configuration file with a line like this:

```
database_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

My unit test are failing and they told me that one of them had the very same issue and changing that path to the correct one fixed his problem.

Now, Where is that file in the Windows XAMPP? I made a search in the whole hard drive (I know mysql must be running for that file to exists, and yes, it is running :)) and I couldn't find it.

This guy is using a file named Parameters.ini where the socket path is specified then he call $container = $kernel->getContainer(); and the database seems to be instantiated.

I tried to changed that file (parameters.ini) which has right now this:

```
database_host = localhost
database_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
database_user = user
database_password = pass
database_schema = lad
```

but if I remove database_socket it complains.

I tried to follow the instructions here: http://www.devside.net/guides/windows/mysql
Setup (changing www with xampp)

Unpack as C:\www\mysql-5.1.56-win32

Rename directory C:\www\mysql-5.1.56-win32 to C:\www\mysql

Copy MySQL configuration file C:\www\mysql\my-medium.ini (or your choice of one of the other included my-*.ini files) to your %SYSTEMROOT% directory

Rename file %SYSTEMROOT%\my-medium.ini (or the copied over my-*.ini file) to my.ini

```
Edit %SYSTEMROOT%\my.ini
```

Under Sections "[client]" and "[mysqld]", edit...

```
socket = C:/www/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Under Section "[mysqld]", insert...

```
basedir = C:/www/mysql/
datadir = C:/www/mysql/data/
```

Restarted mysql, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to put the socket line with an empty value.

```
socket = ""
```

Comment: hey there. I edited in the code line I think you refer to from your question, it'd be great if you'd confirm that.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows `database_host`, `database_user`, `database_password`, `database_schema` and `database_port` (3306) is enough, no need to set `database_socket`.

Comment: is that `database_schema` or should it be `database_name`?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connecting.html#option_general_socket the default name for windows installations is MySQL.

For xampp the default location for the socket is C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock on my machine I do not have a sock file. I tried to get it to create one but without luck.  If you can find a way to create it your going to want to edit /mysql_start.bat to include the commands or edit the default my.ini located in C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini