# XAMPP(LAMPP)'s phpmyadmin throwing error #2002

Tags: html, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, lampp

I have just installed XAMPP(LAMPP) about a hour ago and I am continously searching for the error I am getting on while opening `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`(phpmyadmin). The screen of the error is as follows:
[image: sorry for those tabs]*(sorry for those tabs) :P*

So how can I resolve the error?

I searched on the net and found that my mysql.sock file is missing but I am not getting on how to fix that issue. So how can I bring my mysql.sock file back?

**Thanks in advance :)**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074461/cant-find-where-the-socket-configuration-is-in-xampp-for-windows

May be a solution, check out the last answer.

Answer (score 1):

just start the mysql server using

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

then  you should reconfigure your phpmyadmin using these commands

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

this should fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Though for just locating the file

mysqladmin variables

Check the variable socket.